# Bluetooth is not working ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

This problem seems to be common but i tried all the solutions proposed in previous questions with no luck. my Bluetooth just keep searching for devices and it can't detect them.

output for `rfkill list` :

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

output for `dmesg | grep Blue`:

```
[    1.725292] usb 2-4: Product: Bluetooth Radio 
[   22.987302] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   22.987324] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   22.987326] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   22.987328] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   22.987331] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   24.192938] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: examining hci_ver=06 hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=8723
[   24.192940] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin
[   24.262074] Bluetooth: hci0: rtl: loading rtl_bt/rtl8723b_fw.bin
[   24.279971] Bluetooth: hci0: rom_version status=0 version=1
[   24.279990] Bluetooth: hci0: cfg_sz 0, total size 22496
[   31.827382] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   31.827384] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   31.827387] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   69.606019] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   69.606024] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   69.606029] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  133.549264] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  149.425182] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  165.416224] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  195.195275] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  210.934271] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  227.034314] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  242.896317] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  259.043361] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  274.227449] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  289.383402] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  305.511470] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  321.387453] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  337.520479] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  353.398532] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  369.458540] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  385.298590] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  401.410629] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  417.274763] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  433.471653] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  449.380746] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  465.528845] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  481.409819] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  497.533809] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  513.404936] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  529.532964] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  545.408026] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
```

output for `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb`:

```
0a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:2231]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:b001 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

after trying too many solution i erased the whole disk and installed a fresh 18.04 LTS version (i'm using HP 15 Notebook) but still the same problem.

Comment: If you really "*tried all the solutions proposed in previous questions with no luck*," then you spent a great deal of time and effort. We would be able to help you much better if you edit your question to elaborate on *exactly* what you tried and *exactly* what the results were. As written, we don't know what you tried, or if you tried it correctly.

Comment: I don't seem to have bluetooth at all!  My output for `rfkill list` :

    `0: phy0: Wireless LAN.
    Soft blocked: no.
    Hard blocked: no.`

Umm, should I start a new question? Or can I get some help by a comment?

Comment: can you please review? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224993/bluetooth-on-a-lenovo-g500-stopped-listing-available-connection-results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I partially fixed the problem running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

you might face a problem of a slow wifi connection after that, I fixed it with following commands:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

**IMPORTANT**:
This did not fix the problem totally, I have to close wifi, search and pair bluetooth device then open wifi again. I don't know exactly why is this happening but googling told me that ubuntu drivers are problematic with rtl8723b adapters like mine

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and found this:

"A brilliant developer named Takashi Iwai came up with a solution that I incorporated into the 4.15 kernel

```
sudo apt install git build-essential dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/newbtfix-4.15.git
sudo dkms add ./newbtfix-4.15
sudo dkms install btusb/4.0
```

Reboot"

Found here
[ubuntu 18.04 LTS bluetooth discovery not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032417/ubuntu-18-04-lts-bluetooth-discovery-not-working)

I had to install git manually from Synaptic. I don't understand what it does, but it worked for me.

Comment: already tried that, didn't work.

Comment: That will only fix machines with the 0cf3:3004 Atheros chipset

Comment: did not work for me

Comment: works for me somehow

Comment: can you please review? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224993/bluetooth-on-a-lenovo-g500-stopped-listing-available-connection-results

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem after upgrading the system. I found following error in `/var/log/dpkg.log` :

```
2019-03-23 16:37:24 status half-configured pulseaudio-module-bluetooth:amd64 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.1
2019-03-23 16:37:24 status half-installed pulseaudio-module-bluetooth:amd64 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.1
2019-03-23 16:37:24 status config-files pulseaudio-module-bluetooth:amd64 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.1
2019-03-23 16:37:24 status config-files pulseaudio-module-bluetooth:amd64 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.1
2019-03-23 16:37:24 status config-files pulseaudio-module-bluetooth:amd64 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.1
2019-03-23 16:37:24 status not-installed pulseaudio-module-bluetooth:amd64 <none>
```

So I reinstalled the package, and restarted pulseaudio, which finally solved the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
pulseaudio -k
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Mint and started getting this same "last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)" bluetooth network connection problem after the kernel updated to 4.15.0.33, nothing I did would fix it, but I booted into 4.15.0.32 and it worked again.

So since Ubuntu 18.04 also uses the 4.15 kernel, it's quite likely that you're experiencing the same problem, try booting in on 4.15.0.32 or less and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: this is a question, not an answer, and Mint question must be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What do you mean it's a question? I'm making the statement that using kernel 4.15.0.33 may be the problem.

Comment: Confirmed that this problem occurs on Ubuntu 18.04 for me and is solved by booting into a kernel prior to 4.15.0.33

Comment: This bluetooth networking issue has been fixed in 4.15.0.38 :-)

Comment: See bug repost, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1748565