# Bluetooth on a Lenovo G500 stopped listing available connection results

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, bluetooth, kde, lenovo

I installed Kubuntu on my [Lenovo G500](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/il/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-g-series-laptops/lenovo-g500-notebook/20236/solutions/pd030305), and the Bluetooth didn't show any device results.

I had to install a bios update(3~4 days ago), so I connected a Windows 10 flashdrive (so i can execute an .exe file..) and on the way, tested the Bluetooth on windows 10 - and it worked!

After the bios update, I went to my Kubuntu, and the Bluetooth **was** listing available devices! I connected to my headphones and saved the connection, yey - I have no idea how it worked.

So, I decided to connect my headphones today again & wasn't managed to connect although the previous connection was saved and listed.

I decided to search for devices, and again - no bluetooth devices are listed.

Please help.

```
devwal@devwal-Len:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 105b:e065 Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth module
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 174f:114f Syntek 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub



devwal@devwal-Len:~$ sudo lshw -class communication
  *-communication           
       description: Communication controller
       product: 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 16
       bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
       resources: irq:29 memory:e0614000-e061400f


devwal@devwal-Len:~$ dmesg | grep Blue
[   21.464168] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   21.464188] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   21.464192] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   21.464193] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   21.464196] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   21.897774] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   21.898742] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[   21.914795] Bluetooth: hci0: devwal-Len
[   21.915784] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[   21.943711] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd not found
[   35.960290] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   35.960293] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   35.960300] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  107.175892] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  107.175917] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  107.175930] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  879.416301] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[  879.417321] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[  879.433325] Bluetooth: hci0: devwal-Len
[  879.434316] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[  879.434357] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd not found
[  881.464758] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[  881.466334] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003


devwal@devwal-Len:~/Desktop$  service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-04-07 16:42:05 IDT; 28min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 1018 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─1018 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Apr 07 16:42:05 devwal-Len systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Apr 07 16:42:06 devwal-Len bluetoothd[1018]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
Apr 07 16:42:09 devwal-Len bluetoothd[1018]: Loading LTKs timed out for hci0
Apr 07 16:48:09 devwal-Len bluetoothd[1018]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.59 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Apr 07 16:48:09 devwal-Len bluetoothd[1018]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.59 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Apr 07 16:49:10 devwal-Len bluetoothd[1018]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.59 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Apr 07 16:49:10 devwal-Len bluetoothd[1018]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.59 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Apr 07 16:49:13 devwal-Len bluetoothd[1018]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.59 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Apr 07 16:49:13 devwal-Len bluetoothd[1018]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.59 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Apr 07 17:07:01 devwal-Len bluetoothd[1018]: connect error: Host is down (112)


devwal@devwal-Len:~/Desktop$ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth # Shows all Bluetooth driver info
[   22.016491] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   22.016507] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   22.016510] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   22.016512] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   22.016514] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   22.318157] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   22.319109] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[   22.335161] Bluetooth: hci0: devwal-Len
[   22.339297] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[   22.562555] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd failed with error -2
[   22.562560] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd not found
[   32.625596] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   32.625597] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   32.625610] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   36.235673] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   36.237390] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[  396.299491] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  396.299501] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  396.299514] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  457.377448] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[  457.378461] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[  457.394452] Bluetooth: hci0: devwal-Len
[  457.395447] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[  457.395470] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd failed with error -2
[  457.395473] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd not found
[  459.403604] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[  459.404439] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003



devwal@devwal-Len:/lib/firmware/brcm$ ls
bcm4329-fullmac-4.bin   brcmfmac43236b.bin        brcmfmac4329-sdio.bin   brcmfmac43362-sdio.bin    brcmfmac4350c2-pcie.bin  brcmfmac4356-sdio.bin      brcmfmac4366b-pcie.bin
bcm43xx-0.fw            brcmfmac43241b0-sdio.bin  brcmfmac4330-sdio.bin   brcmfmac4339-sdio.bin     brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin    brcmfmac43570-pcie.bin     brcmfmac4366c-pcie.bin
bcm43xx_hdr-0.fw        brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.bin  brcmfmac43340-sdio.bin  brcmfmac43430a0-sdio.bin  brcmfmac4354-sdio.bin    brcmfmac4358-pcie.bin      brcmfmac4371-pcie.bin
brcmfmac43143.bin       brcmfmac43241b5-sdio.bin  brcmfmac4334-sdio.bin   brcmfmac43430-sdio.bin    brcmfmac43569.bin        brcmfmac43602-pcie.ap.bin  brcmfmac4373.bin
brcmfmac43143-sdio.bin  brcmfmac43242a.bin        brcmfmac4335-sdio.bin   brcmfmac43455-sdio.bin    brcmfmac4356-pcie.bin    brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin     brcmfmac4373-sdio.bin
```

- I have no "Bluetooth on/off" button on my keyboard as far as i know. 
  Most posts mention the F5, But for my pc it's a refresh.
- seems like i have `Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth module` bluetooth but i cannot find an install for it anywhere.
- I tried doing things like disabling and enabling the bluetooth.
- I tried resetting the bluetooth `sudo service bluetooth restart` & `systemctl restart bluetooth.service`

and did this too:

```
devwal@devwal-Len:~$ sudo rfkill list
[sudo] password for devwal: 
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
3: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
5: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
devwal@devwal-Len:~$ sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
devwal@devwal-Len:~$ sudo service bluetooth start
```

non of the above didn't resolve the problem. .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ohhh after a few hours of googling, I have found the best solution for this kind of problem - one of the outputs of the command `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`
was:

```
[22.562560] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd not found
```

the file just doesn't exist in the directory: `/lib/firmware/brcm`

1. Download the missing file from [here](https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/blob/master/brcm/BCM43142A0-105b-e065.hcd).
2. Restart your machine.

and the Bluetooth should be up and running!

Source: https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware

PS: i tried following this solution: https://github.com/jeremyb31/newbtfix-4.15 and it killed my wifi. do not recommend.

Comment: It should work without the github, looks like only firmware is needed

Comment: This saved a lot of time, works on Arch too. Thanks!

Comment: This solution helped me. Also this comment in Launchpad.net by TJ helped me identify exactly which hcd file I need to download from the github repo of winterheart. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1743336/comments/3