# Accidentally installed wrong network drivers on Ubuntu Desktop - How to set to default settings?

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, bluetooth

I had a problem with the Bluetooth on my old Lenovo G500 and tried to install proper drivers for it.

I got to a point where I cannot connect to the wifi, I might have been too "adventurous" while trying too fix the Bluetooth issue.

Is there a way to restore wifi settings to the default ones as it was at the beginning?

**Edit:**

```
  potato@potato-Lenovo-G500:~$ dkms status
  bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 4.13.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed
  bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 4.13.0-45-generic, x86_64: installed
  btusb, 4.0, 4.13.0-45-generic, x86_64: installed
  rtlwifi-new, 0.10: added


  potato@potato-Lenovo-G500:~$ sudo lshw -class network
    *-network               
         description: Ethernet interface
         product: AR8162 Fast Ethernet
         vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
         physical id: 0
         bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
         logical name: enp1s0
         version: 10
         serial: 20:1a:06:1f:9f:29
         capacity: 100Mbit/s
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
         configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
         resources: irq:16 memory:e0500000-e053ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
    *-network UNCLAIMED
         description: Network controller
         product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
         vendor: Broadcom Corporation
         physical id: 0
         bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
         version: 01
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:e0400000-e0407fff
```

Comment: Wifi settings are usually just SSID, password, DNS, static/dinamic, so what does it have to do with "network drivers"? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: If you tell me what drivers you installed, and the **terminal** output of `dkms status`, I'll take a look for you. Please edit this information into your question, and then send a comment to me at @heynnema.

Comment: @heynnema I edited my post please review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding the wi-fi drivers...**

```
sudo dkms remove bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom --all # remove this dkms driver
sudo dkms remove rtlwifi-new/0.10 --all         # remove this dkms driver

See `man dkms` for command assistance, if need be.

sudo apt-get update                             # update the software database
sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms          # install this dkms driver

dkms status                                     # review current dkms status
```

**Regarding the bluetooth drivers/problem...**

Please describe if your bluetooth problem got resolved with the installation of the **btusb** driver. What were you trying to fix?

```
btusb, 4.0, 4.13.0-45-generic, x86_64: installed
```

**Update #1:**

**btusb** is not installed on your current kernel. You need to `sudo dkms remove btusb/4.0 --all` to get this old driver out of your system. Then find a current dkms driver and reinstall it on your current kernel.

Also, check this out [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032417/ubuntu-18-04-lts-bluetooth-0cf33004-discovery-not-working).

**Update #2:**

The user is now booting to the 4.13 kernel, but still has kernel drivers that are not needed, or are not fully installed.

The bcmwl driver needs replacement with the broadcom-sta-dkms driver, as per my previous instructions.

If you're using a Realtek USB wireless dongle, then rtlwifi-new driver needs to have its install completed, with...

```
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.10
```

otherwise, you should remove it, as per my previous instructions.

Comment: worked like charm thanks a lot! I can backup my git project now! the Bluetooth issue still exists. I can see the bluetooth icon on the top, but cant click on it, i dowloaded "bluetooth manager" and it's not detecting anything.

Comment: `broadcom-sta, 6.30.223.271, 4.15.0-29-generic, x86_64: installed ---- broadcom-sta, 6.30.223.271, 4.15.0-34-generic, x86_64: installed ---- btusb, 4.0, 4.13.0-45-generic, x86_64: installed`

Comment: @Kar19 where did you get the btusb driver from? I don't see it in Synaptic. Please edit the details of your last `dkms status` command into your original question, and then delete the comment. btusb is not installed on your current kernel. I assume that you have a usb bluetooth dongle, yes? Also add `lsusb` to the info. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema  I think that btusb 4.0 is a bluetooth fix I did for Atheros 0cf3:3004 bluetooth devices as there are 2 different chipsets with the same ID.  It shouldn't cause any harm

Comment: @Kar19  btusb is only installed on kernel 4.13.0-45, not on your current kernel 4.15.0-34, so it can't work. You'll have to check for a current version and reinstall it via dkms. Also check at this question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032417/ubuntu-18-04-lts-bluetooth-0cf33004-discovery-not-working) for some current problems that folks are having (although this is NOT your current problem).

Comment: @Kar19  ps: you need to `sudo dkms remove btusb/4.0 --all` to get this old driver out of your system.

Comment: @Jeremy31 thanks for the btusb info. The OP has put up a new `dkms status` command that now shows that they're booting to the 4.13 kernel, so the btusb patch is now active again. They still show other drivers that are not used, or not fully installed. Haven't heard back from them.