# 23.04 upgrade interrupted. Kernel 6.2 not fully installed. Bad exit status: 2

Tags: upgrade, kernel, dpkg, partial-upgrade, 23.04

My upgrade was interrupted and now when running upgrades via CLI, getting "bad exit status: 2" and "package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1".

Can boot into Kernel 5.19.  Have tried Mainline to install new kernels but that does not work.

Have tried:  cd /tmp
Download latest stable kernel

```
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v6.2.12/amd64/linux-headers-6.2.12-060212_6.2.12-060212.202304201141_all.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v6.2.12/amd64/linux-headers-6.2.12-060212-generic_6.2.12-060212.202304201141_amd64.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v6.2.12/amd64/linux-image-unsigned-6.2.12-060212-generic_6.2.12-060212.202304201141_amd64.deb
wget -c https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v6.2.12/amd64/linux-modules-6.2.12-060212-generic_6.2.12-060212.202304201141_amd64.deb
```

Install latest stable kernel
`sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

...but same error messages -- see below.

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
(Reading database ... 653860 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-6.2.12-060212_6.2.12-060212.202304201141_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-6.2.12-060212 (6.2.12-060212.202304201141) over (6.2.12-060212.202304201141) ...
Preparing to unpack linux-headers-6.2.12-060212-generic_6.2.12-060212.202304201141_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-6.2.12-060212-generic (6.2.12-060212.202304201141) over (6.2.12-060212.202304201141) ...
Preparing to unpack linux-image-unsigned-6.2.12-060212-generic_6.2.12-060212.202304201141_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-unsigned-6.2.12-060212-generic (6.2.12-060212.202304201141) over (6.2.12-060212.202304201141) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-unsigned-6.2.12-060212-generic.postrm ... removing pending trigger
Preparing to unpack linux-modules-6.2.12-060212-generic_6.2.12-060212.202304201141_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-6.2.12-060212-generic (6.2.12-060212.202304201141) over (6.2.12-060212.202304201141) ...
Setting up linux-headers-6.2.12-060212 (6.2.12-060212.202304201141) ...
Setting up linux-headers-6.2.12-060212-generic (6.2.12-060212.202304201141) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.12-060212-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Binary update-secureboot-policy not found, modules won't be signed

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' -j4 KVER=6.2.12-060212-generic KSRC=/lib/modules/6.2.12-060212-generic/build........(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for 8812au: 5.6.4.2_35491.20191025 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.12-060212-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/make.log for more information.
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.
   ...fail!
run-parts: /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-6.2.12-060212-generic (--install):
 installed linux-headers-6.2.12-060212-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up linux-modules-6.2.12-060212-generic (6.2.12-060212.202304201141) ...
Setting up linux-image-unsigned-6.2.12-060212-generic (6.2.12-060212.202304201141) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-unsigned-6.2.12-060212-generic (6.2.12-060212.202304201141) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 6.2.12-060212-generic
Sign command: /usr/bin/kmodsign
Binary update-secureboot-policy not found, modules won't be signed

Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' -j4 KVER=6.2.12-060212-generic KSRC=/lib/modules/6.2.12-060212-generic/build........^Cdpkg: error processing package linux-image-unsigned-6.2.12-060212-generic (--install):
 installed linux-image-unsigned-6.2.12-060212-generic package post-installation script subprocess was interrupted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-6.2.12-060212-generic
 linux-image-unsigned-6.2.12-060212-generic
```

cat of make.log files shows:

```
/var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build$ cat make.log 
DKMS make.log for 8812au-5.6.4.2_35491.20191025 for kernel 6.2.12-060212-generic (x86_64)
Sun 23 Apr 2023 08:18:53 AM ADT
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/6.2.12-060212-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.2.12-060212-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.2.0-17ubuntu1) 12.2.0
  You are using:           gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.2.0-17ubuntu1) 12.2.0
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_cmd.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_security.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_io.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_debug.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_ioctl_query.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_ioctl_set.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_ieee80211.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_mlme.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_mlme_ext.o
/var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_mlme_ext.c: In function ‘rtw_append_assoc_req_owe_ie’:
/var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_mlme_ext.c:8974:13: warning: the comparison will always evaluate as ‘true’ for the address of ‘owe_ie’ will never be NULL [-Waddress]
 8974 |         if (sec->owe_ie && sec->owe_ie_len > 0) {
      |             ^~~
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/include/drv_types.h:70,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_mlme_ext.c:17:
/var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/include/rtw_security.h:167:12: note: ‘owe_ie’ declared here
  167 |         u8 owe_ie[MAX_OWE_IE_LEN];/* added in assoc req */
      |            ^~~~~~
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_mi.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_wlan_util.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_vht.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_pwrctrl.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_rf.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_chplan.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_recv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_sta_mgt.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_ap.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/mesh/rtw_mesh.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/mesh/rtw_mesh_pathtbl.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/mesh/rtw_mesh_hwmp.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_xmit.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_p2p.o
/var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_ap.c: In function ‘rtw_ap_update_chbw_by_ifbmp’:
/var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_ap.c:4445:42: warning: the comparison will always evaluate as ‘true’ for the address of ‘padapters’ will never be NULL [-Waddress]
 4445 |                 if (!(ifbmp & BIT(i)) || !dvobj->padapters)
      |                                          ^
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_ap.c:17:
/var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/include/drv_types.h:1046:19: note: ‘padapters’ declared here
 1046 |         _adapter *padapters[CONFIG_IFACE_NUMBER];/*IFACE_ID_MAX*/
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_ap.c:4465:42: warning: the comparison will always evaluate as ‘true’ for the address of ‘padapters’ will never be NULL [-Waddress]
 4465 |                 if (!(ifbmp & BIT(i)) || !dvobj->padapters)
      |                                          ^
/var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/include/drv_types.h:1046:19: note: ‘padapters’ declared here
 1046 |         _adapter *padapters[CONFIG_IFACE_NUMBER];/*IFACE_ID_MAX*/
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_rson.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_tdls.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_br_ext.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_iol.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_sreset.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_btcoex_wifionly.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_btcoex.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_beamforming.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_odm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_rm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/rtw_rm_fsm.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/efuse/rtw_efuse.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/os_dep/osdep_service.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/os_dep/linux/usb_intf.o
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:252: /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/os_dep/linux/usb_intf.o] Interrupt
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:252: /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/core/efuse/rtw_efuse.o] Interrupt
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:252: /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/os_dep/osdep_service.o] Interrupt
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:252: /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o] Interrupt
make[1]: *** [Makefile:2027: /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build] Interrupt
make: *** [Makefile:2257: modules] Interrupt
```

Comment: Could be related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2017267 ?

Comment: The mainline kernels are completely unsupported. Please remove, boot to a usable kernel like 5.19 and then try to reinstall the kernel packages which ship in the repo, and paste the results of those. We're not going to support the mainline kernels, but if you show what's going on with the shipped repo kernels we can.

Comment: That crossed my mind as well -- so I tried the following: sudo apt-get purge linux-image-6.2.0-20-generic...
Building module:
Cleaning build area...
'make' -j4 KVER=6.2.12-060212-generic KSRC=/lib/modules/6.2.12-060212-generic/build.......(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for 8812au: 5.6.4.2_35491.20191025 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.2.12-060212-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/8812au/5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/build/make.log for more information.

Comment: ...and other errors as well... seems like I can't get rid of the 6.2 kernel and I'm also unable to fully install it.

Comment: What if you `sudo dpkg -r linux-modules-6.2.12-060212-generic linux-headers-6.2.12-060212-generic linux-image-unsigned-6.2.12-060212-generic linux-headers-6.2.12-060212`?

Comment: Will give it a try -- there's  a bug report out now -- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2017267?comments=all

Comment: sudo dpkg --purge worked!  after finding all the 6.2 linux kernels with sudo dpkg -l | grep "Linux kernel" --but stuck with 5.19 for now!  Guess I'll be staying with that for a while.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @popey: I am also having this exact problem with kernel 6.2.0-20 which was suggested as an upgrade to Ubuntu 23.04 when running 22.10. I wrote this in the bug report.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in **dkms**. I have updated/removed dkms - alx, virtualbox, nvidia. And then installed kernel 6.3.6.

You have a problem with 8812au. There is information here how to delete or update [Accidentally installed wrong network drivers on Ubuntu Desktop - How to set to default settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077753/accidentally-installed-wrong-network-drivers-on-ubuntu-desktop-how-to-set-to-d)