# Intel AC8260 can't find any bluetooth device

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, lenovo, intel-wireless, 18.10

I have installed Ubuntu 18.10 and I can't find any bluetooth devices (I havr tried with 5 different working bluetooth devices).

Laptop: Lenovo X1 Carbon gen.4

Useful info for debug:
uname:

```
$ uname -a
Linux Dm3Ch-X1-Carbon 4.15.0-39-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 23 15:48:01 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

rfkill:

```
$rfkill list
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
5: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

dmesg:

```
dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
[    0.034818] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.094337] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    3.964717] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin (v1.26)
[    4.589388] psmouse serio2: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x0e, buttons: 3/3
[    4.901238] thinkpad_acpi: rfkill switch tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: radio is unblocked
[    4.905368] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.905383] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.905385] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.905387] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.905392] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.957049] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[    4.964050] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[    4.964052] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[    4.964053] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[    4.964053] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[    4.964054] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[    4.964055] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    4.967036] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[    4.977402] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 34.0.1 op_mode iwlmvm
[    6.356683] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[    6.357017] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1368037 usecs
[    6.357054] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[    6.368025] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 10721 usecs
[    6.368604] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
[    6.372114] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[    8.982966] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    8.982967] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    8.982970] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   37.236059] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   37.236068] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   37.236076] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   47.235429] audit: type=1107 audit(1542397111.072:54): pid=762 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=2616 label="snap.whatsdesk.whatsdesk" peer_pid=906 peer_label="unconfined"
[   58.527056] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[   74.412064] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[   90.533392] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  106.414158] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  122.542503] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  138.402049] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  154.528083] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  170.404232] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  186.536074] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  202.404440] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  218.536363] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  234.408117] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  250.533321] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  266.403075] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  282.538309] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  298.406152] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  314.535298] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  330.414096] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  346.528044] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  362.398082] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  378.525068] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  394.404110] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  410.532202] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  426.401457] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  442.524101] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  458.404133] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  474.525138] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  490.402198] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  506.529038] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  522.399041] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  538.525062] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  554.397035] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
```

P.S. I have found a lot of threads like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032417/ubuntu-18-04-lts-bluetooth-0cf33004-discovery-not-working) where described very similar problem and in most of them said that on this version of kernel all should works fine