# Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS Bluetooth device [0cf3:3004] particular issue kernel fixed but not able to find devices

Tags: drivers, 18.04, kernel, bluetooth, ideapad

I have been trying to enable my bluetooth of my laptop (Lenovo Ideapad-Y400), it comes with a Atheros bluetooth that has some problems with the kernel.

First of all I wasn't able to turn on my bluetooth, but I realized that runing `sudo rfkill block bluetooth` twice, and then run againt twice `sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth`, the bluetooth configuration menu was able to find devices and pair them but it crash after 1 minute, then the bluetooth is not able to find anything. Also, if I turn off the bluetooth in that particular case, I'm not able to turn it on again, I have to run again `rfkill un/block` to toggle it on.

Then, I tried the solution from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1043219/688747), and it worked like a charm, now I can turn on and off my bluetooth. Seems the version of my kernel had that problem, also I installed Ukuu, to install a newer kernel, but my graphics card crashes (right now I'm using the patched kernel to make my bluetooth work "Linux 4.15.0.39.48"). **But now my bluetooth can't find any device.**  I tried running `bluetoothctl`, and I powered on it (`power on`), and make it discoverable (`discoverable on`), and also running `scan on` my computer is not able to find any device, same running `hcitool`. Same thing installing `bluez`.

Can you help me with this guys?

Thank you so much.

Here I'm adding some outputs that in some forums ask them to get the context of the system.

`lsusb` output:

---

```
tonny@tonny-IdeaPad:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 413c:2005 Dell Computer Corp. RT7D50 Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1c4f:0054 SiGma Micro 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub    
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 2341:0010 Arduino SA Mega 2560 (CDC ACM)
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 5986:0295 Acer, Inc 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

---

`lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; rfkill list; uname -r; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'` output:

---

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1091] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet [10ec:0123]
    Kernel driver in use: alx
    Kernel modules: alx
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:3218]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
04:00.0 System peripheral [0880]: JMicron Technology Corp. SD/MMC Host Controller [197b:2392] (rev 30)
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 413c:2005 Dell Computer Corp. RT7D50 Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1c4f:0054 SiGma Micro 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 2341:0010 Arduino SA Mega 2560 (CDC ACM)
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 5986:0295 Acer, Inc 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4.15.0-39-generic
[    0.029218] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.062621] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    2.567931] [Firmware Bug]: Duplicate ACPI video bus devices for the same VGA controller, please try module parameter "video.allow_duplicates=1"if the current driver doesn't work.
[    2.567935] [Firmware Bug]: Duplicate ACPI video bus devices for the same VGA controller, please try module parameter "video.allow_duplicates=1"if the current driver doesn't work.
[    2.567939] [Firmware Bug]: Duplicate ACPI video bus devices for the same VGA controller, please try module parameter "video.allow_duplicates=1"if the current driver doesn't work.
[    2.567943] [Firmware Bug]: Duplicate ACPI video bus devices for the same VGA controller, please try module parameter "video.allow_duplicates=1"if the current driver doesn't work.
[    2.567947] [Firmware Bug]: Duplicate ACPI video bus devices for the same VGA controller, please try module parameter "video.allow_duplicates=1"if the current driver doesn't work.
[    3.278355] usb 1-1.3: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[   28.220952] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   28.220966] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   28.220969] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   28.220971] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   28.220976] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  384.853147] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  384.853148] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  384.853151] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  384.859967] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  384.859973] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  384.859978] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  390.827177] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  406.953061] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  415.912118] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  432.037908] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  447.907815] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  464.034678] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  479.904574] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  496.030502] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  511.900372] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  528.026264] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  543.896136] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  560.022140] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  575.891942] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  592.020923] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  607.894811] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  624.023613] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  777.881657] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  794.008537] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  809.879435] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  826.007324] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  841.878218] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  858.005108] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  873.876001] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  890.002848] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  905.872706] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  921.999639] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  937.870565] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  953.997372] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  969.868344] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  985.994169] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1001.865092] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1017.992021] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1033.861796] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1049.988802] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1065.859696] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1081.985522] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1097.856388] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1113.984241] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1129.857239] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1145.985096] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1161.856925] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1177.984835] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1193.856821] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1209.984714] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1225.856513] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1241.983407] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1257.855314] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1273.982145] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1289.854167] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1305.982240] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1321.852850] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1337.979835] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1353.851642] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1369.978715] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1385.849399] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1401.977363] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1417.848295] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1433.975231] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1449.846078] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1465.972883] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1481.843773] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1497.970744] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1513.842642] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1529.969438] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1545.840336] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1561.967232] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1577.838132] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1593.965101] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1609.835897] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1625.962878] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1641.833680] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1657.959569] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1673.830460] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1689.957340] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1705.828338] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1721.955222] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1737.826076] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1753.952992] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1769.823808] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1785.949672] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1801.820675] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1817.947455] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
```

---

### **Edit 1:**

`systemd-analyze blame | nc termbin.com 9999` output:

```
http://termbin.com/yxiq
```

This has inside:

```
4min 29.496s apt-daily-upgrade.service
2min 24.962s apt-daily.service
     29.199s systemd-journal-flush.service
     23.755s dev-sda3.device
     14.333s systemd-udevd.service
     12.446s systemd-sysctl.service
     10.066s snap-core-5662.mount
      6.799s snapd.service
      6.294s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      5.449s NetworkManager.service
      4.790s dev-loop9.device
      4.690s networkd-dispatcher.service
      4.686s dev-loop16.device
      4.563s dev-loop18.device
      4.483s keyboard-setup.service
      4.438s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      4.026s dev-loop8.device
      3.987s dev-loop17.device
      3.953s dev-loop23.device
      3.671s dev-loop13.device
      3.587s dev-loop21.device
      3.521s dev-loop10.device
      3.483s dev-loop24.device
      3.480s winbind.service
      3.239s dev-loop0.device
      3.078s home.mount
      2.961s udisks2.service
      2.915s plymouth-start.service
      2.832s systemd-modules-load.service
      2.563s dev-loop22.device
      2.560s dev-loop20.device
      2.558s dev-loop19.device
      2.557s dev-loop14.device
      2.556s dev-loop15.device
      2.418s dev-loop12.device
      2.416s dev-loop11.device
      2.414s dev-loop7.device
      2.388s grub-common.service
      2.367s apparmor.service
      2.256s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-1d27b8c5\x2db30c\x2d48e3\x2d85ff\x2d4d20591d080f.service
      1.952s dev-loop3.device
      1.852s dev-loop5.device
      1.816s systemd-rfkill.service
      1.617s snap-core-5742.mount
      1.586s gdm.service
      1.582s ModemManager.service
      1.573s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-818.mount
      1.527s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-701.mount
      1.521s dev-loop2.device
      1.517s swapfile.swap
      1.468s dev-loop4.device
      1.450s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-139.mount
      1.353s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-238.mount
      1.333s plymouth-read-write.service
      1.311s wpa_supplicant.service
      1.275s snap-spotify-21.mount
      1.196s snap-spotify-26.mount
      1.192s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-260.mount
      1.169s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-222.mount
      1.167s fstrim.service
      1.144s apport.service
      1.130s fwupd.service
      1.130s snap-spotify-24.mount
      1.114s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-124.mount
      1.082s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      1.024s snap-gnome\x2dlogs-40.mount
      1.012s gpu-manager.service
       997ms systemd-remount-fs.service
       993ms teamviewerd.service
       952ms dev-hugepages.mount
       950ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       949ms dev-mqueue.mount
       937ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-45.mount
       829ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-70.mount
       820ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-808.mount
       813ms accounts-daemon.service
       794ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-117.mount
       776ms dev-loop6.device
       772ms dev-loop1.device
       677ms networking.service
       670ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-57.mount
       647ms systemd-random-seed.service
       619ms snap-vlc-555.mount
       613ms speech-dispatcher.service
       613ms thermald.service
       613ms bluetooth.service
       610ms systemd-logind.service
       608ms avahi-daemon.service
       603ms rsyslog.service
       590ms pppd-dns.service
       577ms packagekit.service
       531ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-51.mount
       487ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-54.mount
       482ms snap-core-5897.mount
       471ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       422ms colord.service
       421ms systemd-journald.service
       314ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       312ms console-setup.service
       297ms binfmt-support.service
       270ms bolt.service
       221ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       211ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-43.mount
       192ms setvtrgb.service
       191ms upower.service
       172ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-74.mount
       170ms systemd-timesyncd.service
       161ms polkit.service
       158ms systemd-resolved.service
       124ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
        90ms snap-firefox-152.mount
        60ms ufw.service
        51ms user@1000.service
        32ms user@121.service
        30ms snapd.seeded.service
         8ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         7ms alsa-restore.service
         7ms ureadahead-stop.service
         7ms kerneloops.service
         6ms rtkit-daemon.service
         6ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
         5ms systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0.service
         5ms dns-clean.service
         2ms systemd-user-sessions.service
         2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         2ms sys-kernel-config.mount
         1ms nvidia-persistenced.service
         1ms snapd.socket
```

Comment: You might want to do a complete shutdown and then boot.  I haven't had to use my fix you linked to for a few kernels now

Comment: Every change I did i rebooted and tried, all combinations failed :/

Comment: I also tried shutting down (not rebooting), while I was experimenting with other kernels, and it is still not working

Comment: Please edit the question to include the URL from terminal for `systemd-analyze blame | nc termbin.com 9999`

Comment: There you have it Jeremy31, thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can try is to blacklist the ath3k and btusb modules

```
echo "blacklist ath3k" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath3k.conf
echo "blacklist btusb" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/ath3k.conf
```

Reboot and wait 30 seconds do

```
sudo modprobe ath3k
sudo modprobe btusb
```

See if it works.  It might be a sign that on old bug has returned involving the timing of the firmware upload for the AR3012 bluetooth

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much Jeremy31!

Comment: Please accept the answer as the solution