# There is no bluetooth device in hcitool dev or rfkill or blueman

Tags: lubuntu, bluetooth, blueman

I cannot find a Bluetooth device to connect to, as a result, `blueman` does not work, and I can't figure out what the problem is.

The weird thing is I cant even find a bluetooth device to begin with, as you can see down here, results of all `hcitool dev` or `rfkill` does not contain anything about a bluetooth device like `hci0`.

I'm using Lubuntu 18.04 LTS and My Laptop is Asus X555L the result of the related commands are given below:

```
$rfkill list 
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$hcitool dev
Devices:

$lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04ca:3010 Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:57b5 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1043:200f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [11ad:0662]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
```

and when I run `blueman-manager` from terminal, I get this in the logs:

```
SetAdapter (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/blueman/gui/DeviceList.py:271)
No such adapter
```

Also, almost all buttons are inactive and I can't do anything in the bluetooth manager.
[image: all buttons in bluetooth manager are inactive]

I don't know what the problem is, the bluetooth device worked on my previous linux OSes and Also on my windows.

Comment: Please edit to include results for `lspci -nnk I grep -iA2 net`

Comment: @Jeremy31 I added the results

Comment: See if https://askubuntu.com/a/1098243/300665 helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by looking at the launchpad bugs in [this link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/714862) and installing `dkms` package along with a `ar3011-dkms` package that was suggested in the link (although I didn't need to install it manually and installing `dkms` using `apt-get` did it automatically) and then restarting my laptop.

And now Bluetooth is working correctly and as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am a little late to the party but if the bluetooth service is running and rfkill is not displaying your bluetooth you may need to ask the kernal to register it.

open up your kernal options and add to the end `pci=nomsi`
restart your computer and you should have bluetooth registered.
[image]