# Bluetooth not discovering devices on Ubuntu 18.04 & Dell Inspiron 3542

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth, dell

I am trying to pair my Bluetooth speaker with my laptop(model: Dell Inspiron 3542)

I am trying this from over a week now and used every solution found on the internet.

I even tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032417/ubuntu-18-04-lts-bluetooth-0cf33004-discovery-not-working?noredirect=1&lq=1) solution but it is not working.

Whenever I am trying to search my Bluetooth speaker, it shows me as the following image.

[Bluetooth forever searching for devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THEyy.png)

I am supplying the output of some commands.

```
kp@devlin:~$ bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# list
Controller AC:D1:B8:D2:1E:E6 ChromeLinux_31A3 [default]
[bluetooth]# devices
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller AC:D1:B8:D2:1E:E6 Discovering: yes
[bluetooth]# power on
Changing power on succeeded
[bluetooth]# 

kp@devlin:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:6a04 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

kp@devlin:~$ rfkill list
0: dell-rbtn: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
7: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
kp@devlin:~$ dmesg | grep Blue
[   17.229294] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   17.229321] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   17.229326] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   17.229329] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   17.229337] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   17.350102] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   17.351087] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[   17.367122] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[   17.367125] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[   17.437473] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[   19.456037] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   21.631788] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   21.631790] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   21.631794] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   33.433294] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   33.433301] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   33.433307] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 1048.039364] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[ 1048.040359] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[ 1048.056394] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[ 1048.056400] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[ 1048.056434] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[ 1050.085335] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[ 1377.020244] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1392.894086] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1761.969305] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1777.846113] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1793.978498] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1809.851781] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1825.981117] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1841.853740] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1857.982819] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1873.854417] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1889.980832] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1905.852787] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1921.978821] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1937.850544] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1953.976194] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1969.846715] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1985.973205] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2001.844633] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2017.972661] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2033.848892] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2049.979862] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2067.648838] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2083.779546] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2099.909565] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2115.782413] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2131.911866] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2147.785892] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2163.914707] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2179.786245] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2195.914849] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2211.787167] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2227.915229] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2243.788302] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2259.915199] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2275.787912] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2291.914610] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2307.786179] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2323.913500] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2339.785130] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2355.912519] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2371.784721] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2387.912105] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2403.783382] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2419.913572] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2435.781665] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2451.907940] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2467.779072] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2483.905092] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2499.777184] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2515.905372] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2531.778022] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 2547.907920] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)

kp@devlin:~$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2019-04-27 11:13:25 IST; 20min ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 1023 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4568)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─1023 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Apr 27 11:13:25 devlin systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Apr 27 11:13:25 devlin bluetoothd[1023]: Starting SDP server
Apr 27 11:13:26 devlin bluetoothd[1023]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 ini
Apr 27 11:13:29 devlin bluetoothd[1023]: Loading LTKs timed out for hci0
Apr 27 11:13:57 devlin bluetoothd[1023]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.70 path=
Apr 27 11:13:57 devlin bluetoothd[1023]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.70 path=
Apr 27 11:14:49 devlin bluetoothd[1023]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.70 pat
Apr 27 11:14:49 devlin bluetoothd[1023]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.70 pat
Apr 27 11:14:55 devlin bluetoothd[1023]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.96 path=
Apr 27 11:14:55 devlin bluetoothd[1023]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.96 path=

kp@devlin:~$ sudo systemctl is-enabled bluetooth.service
enabled
kp@devlin:~$ cat /etc/bluetooth/main.conf | grep -i -E 'DiscoverableTimeout|AutoEnable'
#DiscoverableTimeout = 0
# AutoEnable defines option to enable all controllers when they are found.
AutoEnable=true

kp@devlin:~$ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[   22.106360] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   22.106383] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   22.106387] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   22.106389] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   22.106395] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   23.214304] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   23.215235] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[   23.231250] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[   23.231256] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[   23.292126] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[   23.292131] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[   25.308057] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   32.169411] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   32.169415] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   32.169423] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   34.620101] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   63.106027] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   63.106034] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   63.106041] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
kp@devlin:~$ rfkill
ID TYPE      DEVICE         SOFT      HARD
 0 wlan      dell-rbtn unblocked unblocked
 1 wlan      phy0      unblocked unblocked
 2 wlan      brcmwl-0  unblocked unblocked
 3 bluetooth hci0      unblocked unblocked
kp@devlin:~$ pulseaudio
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.
```

Edit:

after doing steps specified @ [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working)

```
kp@devlin:~$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[   19.863558] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   19.863576] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   19.863580] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   19.863582] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   19.863588] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   19.990391] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   19.991374] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[   20.007412] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[   20.007417] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[   20.063292] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[   20.063296] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[   22.076034] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   26.992912] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   26.992915] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   26.992921] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   29.279488] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   36.330763] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   36.330775] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   36.330785] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   92.542294] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  100.547223] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  116.676067] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  137.412157] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  153.538647] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  169.664917] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  185.534037] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  208.827103] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[  221.370067] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
```

can anyone suggest what else can I do to resolve the issue?

Comment: Please edit your question and post output of the following commands: 1. `sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service`, 2. `sudo systemctl is-enabled bluetooth.service` 3. `cat /etc/bluetooth/main.conf | grep -i -E 'DiscoverableTimeout|AutoEnable'` 4. `sudo lshw | grep -i -A6 "description: Bluetooth"` 5. `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth` 6. `rfkill` and 7. `pulseaudio`. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working)  You can get firmware from https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/blob/master/brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd just copy it to /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM.hcd

Comment: @Marmayogi I have edited question as you asked. output of command `sudo lshw | grep -i -A6 "description: Bluetooth" ` is vanishing while executing it, so cant post that.

Comment: @Jeremy31 downloaded hcd file at /lib/firmware/brcm/. & renamed it as BCM-0a5c-21d7.hcd. pc shutdown and restarted machine. issue is not getting resolved :(

Comment: dmesg says it needs to be /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM.hcd

Comment: so silly of me. Thank you so much @Jeremy31. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

what I was looking was a firmware file for Broadcom Bluetooth.

with the help of @Jeremy31, I found that out using the following command.

```
kp@devlin:~$ dmesg | grep Blue
[   17.229294] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   17.229321] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   17.229326] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   17.229329] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   17.229337] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   17.350102] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   17.351087] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[   17.367122] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[   17.367125] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[   17.437473] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[   19.456037] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   21.631788] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   21.631790] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   21.631794] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   33.433294] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   33.433301] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   33.433307] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 1048.039364] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[ 1048.040359] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[ 1048.056394] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[ 1048.056400] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[ 1048.056434] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[ 1050.085335] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[ 1377.020244] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1392.894086] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[ 1761.969305] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
```

keep a note of .hcd file name which is required as shown in the above command output on line 10 & line 22.(which is BCM.hcd in this case)

we can make that file using steps shown here [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working)

OR

you can download it using following commands one by one.

install git if have not yet

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

download .hcd file

```
git clone https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/blob/master/brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd
```

copy .hcd file to /lib/firmware/brcm directory

```
cp BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/.
```

rename .hcd file with the name which is required(as noted in the command output of the first step)

```
mv BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd BCM.hcd
```

**shutdown pc(not reboot)** & start again