# Ubuntu 18.04.1 Bluetooth not enabling Kernel Version 5.3.0-28-generic

Tags: 18.04, kernel, bluetooth, hp, settings

I have done almost everything on askubuntu to make this work but my bluetooth still won't start.

[Bluetooth Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YdIL.png)

[Drop Down Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iliKS.png)

Below is some extra info:-

```
prateek@prateek-HP-Laptop-15-da0xxx:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net;lsusb
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:84a6]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723de
Kernel modules: rtl8723de
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b009 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05c8:03c7 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink)

prateek@prateek-HP-Laptop-15-da0xxx:~$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[   16.519650] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   16.519669] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   16.519675] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   16.519678] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   18.976982] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   27.201269] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: HCI_OP_READ_LOCAL_VERSION failed (-110)
[   33.432204] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   33.432205] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   33.432209] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized

prateek@prateek-HP-Laptop-15-da0xxx:~$ rfkill list; uname -r; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
5.3.0-28-generic
[    0.121399] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.198461] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[   16.519650] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   16.519669] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   16.519675] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   16.519678] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   16.519681] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   16.760751] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
[   18.976982] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   19.343858] rtl8723de: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723defw.bin
[   27.201269] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: HCI_OP_READ_LOCAL_VERSION failed (-110)
[   33.432204] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   33.432205] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   33.432209] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

I have also tried the [Tekashi Iwai's bluetooth fix](https://askubuntu.com/a/1043219/740708) for kernel 4.15 but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Similar problem here. ```hciconfig hci0 up``` returns Can't get device info: No such device