# Bluetooth not discovering devices Ubuntu 18.04.04

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth, hp

I can turn Bluetooth on and it shows the animation of discovering new devices, but it does not find any of my bluetooth devices. I have checked my devices with another PC. I went through several other answers, but they did not help me. I have attached the output of commands that I think are relevant. I tried restarting bluetooth with `systemctl` as well.

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; hciconfig -a; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:2230]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
--
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:229c]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:216c Broadcom Corp. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth Device
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:0050 Validity Sensors, Inc. Swipe Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b40e Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP Truevision HD camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 74:29:AF:E1:13:12  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:10771 acl:0 sco:0 events:909 errors:0
    TX bytes:26537 acl:0 sco:0 commands:843 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xfe 0xcf 0xfe 0xdb 0xff 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'mojito'
    Class: 0x1c010c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer
    Device Class: Computer, Laptop
    HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0x0
    LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x210b
    Manufacturer: Broadcom Corporation (15)

[    0.123052] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.164518] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.977086] [Firmware Bug]: Invalid critical threshold (0)
[    8.693513] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    8.693530] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    8.693534] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    8.693536] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    8.693540] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    8.874387] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[    8.875393] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[    8.891382] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[    8.892379] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[    8.897985] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd failed with error -2
[    8.897989] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd not found
[    9.190222] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PXSX) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[   10.915901] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   10.916386] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[   11.338440] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   11.338442] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   11.338447] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   19.921512] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   19.921520] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   19.921525] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 1036.768127] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[ 1036.769115] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[ 1036.785193] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[ 1036.786135] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[ 1036.786167] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd failed with error -2
[ 1036.786170] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd not found
[ 1038.810441] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[ 1038.811129] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[15624.075374] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[15624.076354] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[15624.092379] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[15624.093372] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[15624.093387] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd failed with error -2
[15624.093389] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd not found
[15626.105200] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[15626.106462] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[15895.087186] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[15895.088196] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[15895.104186] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[15895.105182] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[15895.105209] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd failed with error -2
[15895.105211] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd not found
[15897.117743] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[15897.119350] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[16310.894392] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[16310.895386] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[16310.911430] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[16310.912382] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[16310.912399] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd failed with error -2
[16310.912401] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd not found
[16312.932948] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[16312.934460] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[16768.987001] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[16768.988000] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[16769.004009] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[16769.005006] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[16769.005025] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd failed with error -2
[16769.005027] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd not found
[16771.008944] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[16771.010068] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[54194.947375] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[54194.948375] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[54194.964373] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[54194.965444] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[54194.965469] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd failed with error -2
[54194.965472] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd not found
[54196.981370] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[54196.982382] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[75739.177149] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[75739.178162] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[75739.194230] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[75739.195157] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[75739.195196] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd failed with error -2
[75739.195200] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd not found
[75741.211310] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[75741.212196] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[81232.873908] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[81232.874906] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[81232.890923] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[81232.891910] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[81232.891947] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd failed with error -2
[81232.891950] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd not found
[81234.924050] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[81234.924917] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[99110.007627] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[99110.008614] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[99110.024624] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[99110.025613] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[99110.025628] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd failed with error -2
[99110.025630] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd not found
[99112.029750] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[99112.030621] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[105617.080258] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[105617.081255] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[105617.097267] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[105617.098268] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[105617.098308] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd failed with error -2
[105617.098312] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd not found
[105619.118434] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[105619.119415] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[106466.212654] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[106466.213733] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[106608.259142] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[106608.259815] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[107182.781260] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[107182.782107] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[107243.612671] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[107243.614270] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[107574.361287] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[107574.362328] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[107589.693161] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[107589.694339] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[107597.401101] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[107597.402353] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
```

My `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` looks like (everything else is commented out):

```
[General]
[Policy]
AutoEnable=true
```

I checked that I have the file mentioned in the error:-

```
$  ls /lib/firmware/brcm/
BCM20702A1-13d3-3411.hcd  brcmfmac43241b0-sdio.bin  brcmfmac4335-sdio.bin     brcmfmac4354-sdio.bin      brcmfmac4366b-pcie.bin
BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd  brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.bin  brcmfmac43362-sdio.bin    brcmfmac43569.bin          brcmfmac4366c-pcie.bin
bcm4329-fullmac-4.bin     brcmfmac43241b5-sdio.bin  brcmfmac4339-sdio.bin     brcmfmac4356-pcie.bin      brcmfmac4371-pcie.bin
bcm43xx-0.fw              brcmfmac43242a.bin        brcmfmac43430a0-sdio.bin  brcmfmac4356-sdio.bin      brcmfmac4373.bin
bcm43xx_hdr-0.fw          brcmfmac4329-sdio.bin     brcmfmac43430-sdio.bin    brcmfmac43570-pcie.bin     brcmfmac4373-sdio.bin
brcmfmac43143.bin         brcmfmac4330-sdio.bin     brcmfmac43455-sdio.bin    brcmfmac4358-pcie.bin
brcmfmac43143-sdio.bin    brcmfmac43340-sdio.bin    brcmfmac4350c2-pcie.bin   brcmfmac43602-pcie.ap.bin
brcmfmac43236b.bin        brcmfmac4334-sdio.bin     brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin     brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin
```

I tried several things, but still cannot figure out what's wrong. I will greatly appreciate any comments about what I can try.

Comment: Where did you get the `BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd` file?

Comment: I am not sure what was wrong, but this answer helped: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032417/ubuntu-18-04-lts-bluetooth-0cf33004-discovery-not-working

Comment: That answer is 100% unrelated to your problem. It is about Atheros devices in old kernels.

Comment: As I said, I am not sure what was wrong, but it worked

Comment: OK, I am VTC as norepro.