# Bluetooth not working on ubuntu 18.04 (Dell inspirion 11 3148)

Tags: drivers, 18.04, bluetooth

Recently I did a dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04,
but I am having issues with Bluetooth not discovering devices. It just keeps on searching for devices. However, the Bluetooth is visible in other devices.

I tried pretty much everything I found. I tried these:

1. [ubuntu 18.04 LTS bluetooth [0cf3:3004] discovery not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032417/ubuntu-18-04-lts-bluetooth-0cf33004-discovery-not-working)
2. https://www.devmanuals.net/install/ubuntu/ubuntu-16-04-LTS-Xenial-Xerus/how-to-install-bluetooth.html

Running:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; rfkill list; uname -r; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
```

gives:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [1028:0018]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:216a Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f3:0396 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0c45:64cb Microdia 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0483:91d1 STMicroelectronics Sensor Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
5.4.0-74-generic
[    0.010558] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.059276] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    4.629272] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.629302] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.629307] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.629310] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.629314] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.848235] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[    4.849239] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x06
[    4.963369] Bluetooth: hci0: VANP-Inspiron-11-3148
[    4.964282] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A0 (001.001.011) build 0000
[    4.969977] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216a.hcd failed with error -2
[    4.969981] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216a.hcd not found
[    6.805812] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.805815] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.805822] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    6.984108] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[    6.986230] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0x1003
[   21.246799] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   21.246805] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   21.246811] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

The Bluetooth window is fixed as shown in this screenshot and never changes:

[image: Bluetooth window]

I am new to Linux so try to elaborate a bit on any commands you may suggest.

Comment: *Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216a.hcd failed with error -2* <- This seems to be the problem.

Comment: @ChanganAuto so is this a network card error?
but bluetooth  is working well in Windows 10

Comment: No, not an hardware error. The firmware is missing or something wrong with the driver.

Comment: @ChanganAuto what should be the recommended drivers

Comment: Not sure it helps (the WiFi works so...) but you can try https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers